# Polymer core-input committedValue event

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using the attribute committedValue  of core-input element of Polymer like this:

```
<paper-input is="core-input" type="text" name="data_in" id="data_in" value="{{current_data_in}}" committedValue="{{committed_data_in}}"></paper-input>
```

It works fine, and it solves the problem of listening to some `keypress + blur` events to determine the input is `"committed"`.

My problem is that I'd like to erase the contents of the input box value after the value were committed. I can't find any way to listen to this event.

Is there any built-in event that being triggered after a value is committed?

Comment: why not to use native event listener and then change the value to empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way to do it and it includes observing the committedValue like this:

```
  <script>
Polymer('chat-element', {
  ready: function() {
    this.committed_data_in = "";
    this.current_data_in = "";
  },
  observe: {
    'committed_data_in': 'modelUpdated'
  },
  modelUpdated: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue);
  }
});
```